# Validating given input and printing every prime number =< given input. (Python)

Tags: python, validation, input, primes

So I have read tons of solutions to this type of questions, but they all seem to be way too complicated, or I can't find any useful solutions in them.

I have written the first part where I have to ask for an input and validate it to be an integer, but I can't figure out how to write the code for the second part. Efficiency isn't a necessity here, but I think it's better if I learn the most efficient way from the get go. From what I read, using the radicle of the input and checking the divisors is the way to go here, but as I said, I can't figure out how to actually write the code and integrate it into what I already have.

```
while True:
    x = str(input("Please enter an integer:  "))
    try:
        x = int(x)
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a valid integer: ")
        continue
    
    break
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: *...but they all seem to be way too complicated...* What's way too complicated? *...but I think it's better if I learn the most efficient way from the get go...* What if the most efficient way is a method that you've already decided is "way too complicated"? See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/2068372/238704

Comment: Maybe I couldn't express myself well enough, I read multiple solutions to the same problem, and many different ones were mentioned. I was confused about which one was the "best one".  It's been only a few days since I started coding, and I'm a bit confused about what to learn first in order to be as efficient as possible. Thank you very much for the provided link. Hope you have a great day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to edit multi-line code into your question, rather than post a comment, because then you are not limited to a single line.

Your code appears to be:

```
def is_prime2(n):
   if n == 2 or n == 3:
     return True
   #endif
   if n % 2 == 0 or n < 2:
     return False
   #endif
   for i in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1, 2):
     if n % i == 0:
       return False
     #endif
   #endfor
   return True
#enddef
print(n)
```

I have added comments to indicate where I think that various statements end. I may have mistaken the indentation converting from a single line.

Apart from that `print(n)`, which is either not part of the function definition or comes after a `return`, this appears to work correctly. It will be too slow for very large values of `n` though it will be fine for smaller values and for testing. For very large values have a look at the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Answer (score 0):

Write an `isPrime(n)` function that returns `true` if n is prime, `false` otherwise. Then test all the numbers from 2 up to the entered integer to see if they are prime.

We will help you to improve your code, but you have to write it first.

Comment: I have added this part, `def is_prime2(n):
    if n == 2 or n == 3:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0 or n < 2:
        return False
    for i in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True


print(n)
`